# Box shadow in IE 8 without Active X

Tags: activex, css

Is there way how to use box shadow for IE 8 when active x is disabled?
So i cant use filtrs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link might help.

all sides shadow:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=0),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=90),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=180),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Color=#cccccc, Strength=5, Direction=270);
```

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/